# Best way to select nonclustered index on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am developer and not a DBA. But in my current project I am facing SQL query performance issues very badly with both types of queries, i.e. CPU and memory consumption. I can't share my actual table structure here but we can consider below as almost same structure.

**ProductTbl**

```
ProductId BIGINT
CustomerId BIGINT
ProductCode NVARCHAR(50)
ProductName NVARCHAR(250)
ProductImage NVARCHAR(250)
IsDeleted BIT
IsActive BIT
```

**OrderTbl**

```
OrderId BIGINT
CustomerId BIGINT
ProductCode NVARCHAR(50)
OrderDate DATETIME2(7)
Quantity INT
```

We can't add `ProductId` in `OrderTbl` because we are receiving order details from third party and we may get the P`roductCode` which is not in `ProductTbl` (or which can be add into or delete from `ProductTbl` any time).

And below are some sample queries

```
SELECT
    ProductId,  
    CustomerId, ProductCode, ProductName, ProductImage
FROM 
    ProductTbl
WHERE 
    CustomerId = @CustomerId 
    AND ProductCode = @ProductCode  
    AND IsDeleted = 0 
    AND IsActive = 1

SELECT
    CustomerId, ProductCode, ProductName, ProductImage
FROM 
    ProductTbl pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OrderTbl ot ON pt.ProductCode = ot.ProductCode
WHERE 
    pt.CustomerId = @CustomerId 
    AND pt.ProductCode = @ProductCode 
    AND pt.IsDeleted = 0 
    AND pt.IsActive = 1
    AND OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Now, I have few questions like below

1. Should I create a nonclustered index on separate columns, OR should I go with multiple columns in one index?
2. Does sequence matter while creating a nonclustered index on multiple columns?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how or if you should create an index, or do you want to know how to get your query to use the non clustered index? Your question title and the questions at the end of your post aren't in sync.

Comment: Thank you @Eli for you quick response. Hosting guys told me to apply Indexes and even I had applied few very straight forward indexes like on CustomerId asc on ProductTbl and for last few months it was working well. But data is increased cause of no.of customers. I am almost done with 100's of stored procedures and now I just want to set Indexes so my Stored procedures can work as expected.

Comment: Broadly speaking, as you get more data into your tables, you need more precise indexing for your queries. Yes, when using multiple columns, the sequence of columns can matter - choosing your most selective direct lookup column (i.e. WHERE column = value) first is your fastest option.

Answer (score 1):

to use your numbering format:

1. you should create minimum, yet, covering indexes for your queries. These indexes should contain all columns which you'll need for your stored procedure(s). Try to add more columns if that will make the index usable for multiple stored procedures. More indexes = more writes to the database for each insert/modify on that table - you may want to keep that in mind and not create oodles of indexes
2. sequence matters - you bet!

here's a video from a world-class DBA which explains the 2 points which I've mentioned, as well as explain what's going on under the hood. I've found this information to be invaluable in index tuning.
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/01/how-to-think-like-the-engine-2019-edition/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017) is a helpful article I often use while working on index design as a regular developer.